# High CPU usage when JRebel is on

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, prettyfaces, jrebel

When turning on JRebel for my JSF project, CPU usage gets too high on each requests & drops down when request has been served. I did looked though the profiler but it was not caused due to my project classes itself. But I could even figure out the culprit looking at the profiling results. Here are the profiling results :

[image]

[image]

Interestingly the problem disappears when I

1. either disable JRebel,
2. or remove a 3rd party URL rewrite library (`com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.*`).

But then I created a new fresh netbeans project without disabling either of the above two, & but still the problem is not there, which expectedly should have been.

Any idea what may be causing this ?

## Edit:

Seems `Prettyfaces` (`com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces`) URL rewrite library is the culprit anyway..
See this snapshot:[image]

But why this happens only when Jrebel is on ??

Comment: Please add -Drebel.log=true -Drebel.log.perf=true to VM arguments, reproduce the workflow and send jrebel.log, written to {user.home}/.jrebel/jrebel.log to JRebel's support. JRebel probably does some excessive scanning in your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in JRebel 5.5.0 prettyfaces plugin, you can either disable it, or use JRebel nightly build (or JRebel 5.5.1+ once available), which contains the fixed version.

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/early-access/

Comment: oh I didn't even realized there may be a prettyfaces plugin..now trying after disabling that..

Comment: even after disabling all plugins the CPU load does not reduce.. there is an increased latency to load pages from localhost..

Comment: Please send the issue to JRebel support. support@zeroturnaround.com .
Don't forget to include a performance log. http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/sending-log/ . Also make sure you are running the latest JRebel 5.5.2

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this. This is definitely an issue with JRebel 5.5.0.

I worked around this problem by using JRebel 5.4.2 instead.

Comment: did you also had the same setup (jsf/prettyfaces) ? What was eating CPU in your case 
?

Comment: The PrettyFaces configuration is cached in a field which JRebel seems to clear for some reason. That's why PrettyFaces is rebuilding it's configuration for each request which takes some time due to the annotation scanning.

Comment: is jrebel doing right by clearing it on each request, instead of doing when there are changed made.. I think the bug is in the jrebel, right ? Strangely this does not happen in the fresh project that I created with same setup.

Comment: It's a bug in JRebel.