# Prettyfaces consuming high CPU

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces, jrebel

When turning on JRebel for my JSF project, CPU usage gets too high on each requests & drops down when request has been served. I did looked though the profiler but it was not caused due to my project classes itself.

`Prettyfaces`  seems to be the real culprit here..
See this snapshot:

[image]

& this

[image]

[image]

See this snapshot:[image]

But why this high CPU usage by Prettyfaces happens only when Jrebel is on, what is causing this ? Where is the problem actually ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782940/high-cpu-usage-when-jrebel-is-on Please add -Drebel.log=true -Drebel.log.perf=true to VM arguments, reproduce the workflow and send jrebel.log, written to {user.home}/.jrebel/jrebel.log to JRebel's support. JRebel probably does some excessive scanning in your setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in JRebel 5.5.0 prettyfaces plugin. You can either disable it, or use JRebel nightly build or JRebel 5.5.1+

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/early-access/

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this. This is definitely an issue with JRebel 5.5.0.

I worked around this problem by using JRebel 5.4.2 instead.